# BrainTree error HTTP 406 when creating subscription plan in production

Tags: braintree, production

I'm using BrainTree recurring billing in sandbox and everything works fine. However, when I want to create subscription plan in **production**, I got 406 HTTP error in browser.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted support and they replied with fixed URL, which works.
There's incorrect URL defined within the New Plan button ending with "..new.plan". After deleting ".plan" it works.
Probably will be fixed soon.